# Android NDK socket connect() returning 0 when it should fail whilst on 3g

Tags: android, c, tcp, android-ndk

I have written a socket in the android NDK and a server in c. It is able to connect to the server fine. However if the server is down or I try to get it to connect to a different random IP the call to connect still returns 0 when it should return -1.

Here is the code for the client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define APPNAME "MyApp"
#define logcat(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, __VA_ARGS__)


int createSocket() {
    int sockFD;
    if ((sockFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        logcat("Unable to create socket");
        return -1;
    }

    logcat("Socket created: %i", sockFD);
    return sockFD;


}
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_myapp_client( JNIEnv* env,
                                      jobject thiz ) {
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int sockFD, new_socket;
    char * message;
    if ((sockFD = createSocket()) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server ip);
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);
    new_socket = connect(sockFD, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
    logcat("Connect return value: %i", new_socket);

    int rtn = recv(sockFD, message, sizeof(char), 0);
    logcat("Message: %i", rtn);

    close(sockFD);

    return 1;
}
```

A valid descriptor is made for the socket, the return values for connect and recv are zero when I run this without my server running. Might be worth noting the android device is connected to the internet over mobile internet.

Comment: That code is just for trying to work out whats going wrong. The server is not running so cannot accept the connection, I have literally unplugged the ethernet cable to the server and it still "connects" to it.

Comment: What is `server ip`? I have occasionally seen `connect()` wrongly succeed to `127.0.0.1` but never to an external IP address.

Comment: It's an external IP

Answer (score 0):

I removed android specific parts

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int createSocket() {
    int sockFD;
    if ((sockFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Unable to create socket");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Socket created: %i", sockFD);
    return sockFD;


}
int main() {
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int sockFD, new_socket;
    char * message;
    if ((sockFD = createSocket()) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);
    new_socket = connect(sockFD, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
    printf("Connect return value: %i", new_socket);

    int rtn = recv(sockFD, message, sizeof(char), 0);
    printf("Message: %i", rtn);

    close(sockFD);

    return 1;
}
```

This works as expected. Try it yourself by connecting to `127.0.0.1`. If there is no server running on your host machine then it will fail to connect (connect will return -1 and errno will be set appropriately).

Make sure the IP address you are using for connection is really pointing to your server.

Also there is a problem in recv:

```
int rtn = recv(sockFD, message, sizeof(char), 0);
```

Variable `message` is a pointer that has not be assigned to any memory (it contains some stack garbage value) and you are overwriting it. See [manual for recv (2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html).

To fix this you should either assign your pointer to some allocated memory:

```
message = malloc(1); //char is always a single byte
```

or use stack instead of heap for storing the message byte:

```
char message;
...
int rtn = recv(sockFD, &message, sizeof(char), 0);
```

I assumed your message is always a single byte.

Keep in mind that in here:

```
printf("Message: %i", rtn);
```

you are printing the return code not the actual message.

Comment: It works fine when connecting to my server however when the server is not running or I try to connect to a port that isnt accepting connections it still returns 0 so I have no way to tell if a connection has been made or not

Comment: It's still returning 0 when the server isn't running