# socket() not throwing an exception despite server not running

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have written a client to run on an android device (android 6) and when the server is up and running it connects, however when the server is down the socket() call should throw an exception however it doesn't.

I originally tried it using the NDK and ran into a very similar issue ([Android NDK socket connect() returning 0 when it should fail whilst on 3g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150532/android-ndk-socket-connect-returning-0-when-it-should-fail-whilst-on-3g)).

I am assuming this is a bug with android at this point but any insight into a solution or work around would be much appreciated.

The code in question:

```
public class Client implements Runnable{

    private Socket socket;
    private InetAddress IP;
    private int port;

    public Client(int port){
        try {
            this.IP = InetAddress.getByName(server ip);
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e){
            Log.d("App1", "Unknown Host, connection failed");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        this.port = port;
        Log.d("App1", "initialised");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            this.socket = new Socket(this.IP, this.port);
            Log.d("FiX1", "Connected");
            listen();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            Log.d("FiX1,","connection failed");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        finally
        {
            try{
                socket.close(); // dispose
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.exit(1);
            }

        }


    }

   public void listen() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while (true) {
                String cominginText = "";
                try {
                    cominginText = in.readLine();
                    Log.d("FiX1",cominginText);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //error ("System: " + "Connection to server lost!");
                    System.exit(1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could find was to manually send an acknowledgement from the server that a connection had been made, the client would retry the connection if it did not receive this message within a certain time after it claimed to have connected.

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference between a TCP connection "close" vs "disconnect". 
If you close the socket connection from server using socket.close() then you will get exception in client side, if you try to read from that connection or vice versa.

However, if one side just disappears(shut down the program) then the other side has no way of knowing that. So the other side will wait for response for read call.

The TCP protocol was designed to be reliable in hostile communication environments and it will not normally decide a connection is closed just because it has not heard from the other side for a while.